# Eclipse + Apache Velocity Engine?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jar, virtual-machine, velocity

New to Appache Velocity and attempting to run my first vm page in Eclipse (without success).  Here's the steps I've taken so far:

1. Download the Velocity Engine Distribution: http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi#Engine
2. Create a Dynamic-Web Project in Eclipse
3. Choose Tomcat as the server
4. Create a simple index.vm file in the WebContent folder
5. Add all jar files from the velocity-1.7.zip to my Project ClassPath
6. Run the index.vm, outputs all the VTL as is (not "vm-ized").

**index.vm:**

```
<html>
<body>
#set( $foo = "Velocity" )
Hello $foo World!
</body>
<html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it working in Eclipse.  Simply needed to add all the Velocity Jar files to the lib directory of the WEB-INF folder in my Dynamic Web Project.  Then update the web.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Velocity_Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.vm</welcome-file>  
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- Define Velocity template compiler -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map *.vm files to Velocity -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add-on question.  I removed the jars from the lib folder and added them to my class-path instead.  It threw a bunch of errors.  Can I point to the all the Velocity Jar files externally, or do I need to import them to the lib folder of my project for this to work?  Thanks!

Comment: Hey there could you provide an example of your velocity project? I want to set one up but I am having difficulties. Could you perhaps share your project folder so I can see where the files go?

Thank!